# Facebook API: How to get user blocked list

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I built an app on Facebook.

- To block someone:

  - Click the account menu  at the top right of any Facebook page and choose **Privacy Settings**.
  - Scroll to the **Blocked People and Apps** section and click **Manage Blocking**.
  - Enter the name or email address of the person you want to block and click **Block**. People will **not** be notified when you block them.
- My issue is:

  - How can I check the blocked status between of two Facebook's users using Facebook API on my app? Or any ways to get blocked list from current user.

Answer (score 2):

**page_blocked_user**

An FQL table that can be used to return a list of a users that are blocked from a Facebook Page.

The Page Graph API object has an equivalent blocked connection that can also be used to block or unblock users.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_blocked_user/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my app did not create a Facebook Page. So I can not use FQL "page_blocked_user"

I used to try your way before, but it return empty. Thanks